# What is the logic behind this recursive program to find factorial in c++?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorial(int x)
{
    if(x == 1)
    { 
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return x*factorial(x-1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout<<factorial(5)<<endl;
}
```

I don’t get the part when the value reaches 1. Why doesn't the program print 1 as the output, because when 1 is reached it returns 1. Consider the below steps.

`5*factorial(4)=5*4*factorial(3)=5*4*3*factorial(2)=5*4*3*2*factorial(1)`

So now, when the `x` value becomes 1 and goes into  if , condition becomes true and 1 is returned. So why doesn't it output 1? Is it that the value of the `5*4*3*2*factorial(1)` is stored somewhere and the returned value of just gets multiplied with `5*4*3*2*1` and outputs 120?

Also please explain, what happens when we pass 0 instead of 5,how will it output 1? (0!=1)

Comment: I am confused as to why this is even a question? You can easily run this in a compiler and step through the code to see the beviour

Comment: "...when we pass 0 instead of 5,how will it output 1?" - what made you think it will output 1 in that case? It won't really. Most likely it will simply crash.

Comment: If you already know that previous recursive calls are equivalent to in `5*4*3*2*factorial(1)` sequence, then what problems are you having with making the last step and understanding that the whole thing is `5*4*3*2*1`, which is `120`?

Comment: it is not that easy for beginners to understand recursive functions... I also don't see a reason to vote this question down. He posted code and only wants to understand.

Comment: @Leon If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is exactly like you said:

```
5*factorial(4)=5*4*factorial(3)=5*4*3*factorial(2)=5*4*3*2*factorial(1)
```

So if it reaches 1 then this will be replaced by

```
5*factorial(4)=5*4*factorial(3)=5*4*3*factorial(2)=5*4*3*2*1
```

so the result of the last step goes into the second last step.... where 2*1 will be calculated... After that the 3rd last step gets the value of 2*1 = 2 and multiplies 3 on in and so on.

If you insert smaller or equal 0 into your function, you will get an endless recursion because if(0 == 1). But if you replace this code with

```
int factorial(int x)
{
    if(x <= 1)
    { 
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return x*factorial(x-1);
    }

}
```

Then also 0 and -numbers will work

Comment: Why you have an `else if` and not simply omit the who else if statement? Now you have a branch that never returns, although that branch will never be reached.

Comment: np, we are here to help each other ;)

Comment: it was because I thought 0! = 0 but thats wrong... 0! = 1! = 1 ;)

Comment: For x < 1 it has undefined behaviour. (It would try to subtract 1 from the minimum integer.) That doesn't mean it does anything in particular.

Comment: @Thomas    Thanks for your help.Seems like the question has offended many.

Comment: @Enigma you are welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

The stack stores in some sense all pending operations. As soon as fact(2) gets 1 from the call, it multiplies it by 2 and returns 2. fact(3) receives that 2, multiplies it by 3 and returns 6. fact(4) receives that 6, multiplies it by 4 and returns 24. And so on...

Passing a 0 was not thought of in the current form of the program and will actually cause the program to crash (most likely). Changing the if(x==1) line to if(x==0) will fix this.

Comment: It will crash due to stack overflow or maybe it will reach 1 again after a long time if the stack can be made large enough. If the stack doesn't overflow and it does reach that 1, it will return a zero.

Comment: (or at least that I'd expect from a program that does work correctly on cases with n>=1)

Comment: Well, it isn't obviously UB (but whenever I mention stack overflow I do kind of imply UB by the mere fact that the compiler is allowed to assume such a stack overflow won't occur)

Comment: The undefined behaviour for x < 1 is because of the eventual underflow from x - 1 when x gets to the minimum integer. It has nothing to do with stack overflow. And when a program has undefined behaviour, it can do anything at all.

Comment: Does underflow also cause UB on unsigned integers?

Comment: No, unsigned underflow wraps modulo the appropriate power of 2. But int underflow gives UB.

Comment: Thanks. So it's only the signed integers that give issues (I've seen another such bug where someone requested GCC to not optimize out checks for overflow)